# JoltTransformJson - How to get column names as values

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

i have JSON value as below :

```json
{
  "table": "table_name",
  "op_type": "U",
  "before": {
    "AAAA": "1-1111",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 03:57:01"
  },
  "after": {
    "AAAA": "1-1111",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 10:10:34",
    "DDDD": "2023-08-31 23:59:59"
  }
}
```

I want to add column_names field like this :

,"changed_columns": "AAAA,BBBB,DDDD"

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following specs in which the main idea is to arrange the attributes so as to generate an array with unique elements within the an array by using successive **shift** transformation, then combine them within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    // combine common key names for each respective values for the attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "before|after": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // construct an array from those newly formed keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "changed_columns"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // make them comma-separated 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(',',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

***Edit*** : If your aim is to keep newly generated attribute along with the existing ones, then you can prefer using the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", //else case
      "before|after": {
        "*": {
          "$": "cc.&",
          "@": "&2.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "cc": {
        "*": {
          "$": "changed_columns"
        }
      },
      "*": "&" //else case
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "changed_columns": "=join(',',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. How can i add it along with other fields ?

in that :

{
  "table": "table_name",
  "op_type": "U",
  "before": {
    "AAAA": "1-1111",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 03:57:01"
  },
  "after": {
    "AAAA": "1-1111",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 10:10:34",
    "DDDD": "2023-08-31 23:59:59"
  },
  "changed_columns" : "AAAA,BBBB,DDDD"
}

Comment: as an extra i want to do this how can i do? AAAA: "If you have after.AAAA, take AAAA else before.AAAA", BBBB: "If you have after.BBBB, take BBBB else before.BBBB"

Comment: Hi, I asked the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435538/jolttransformjson-json-transformation