# JoltTransformJson - Json Transformation

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

i have JSON value as below :

```json
{
  "table": "table_name",
  "op_type": "U",
  "before": {
    "AAAA": "1-1111",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 03:57:01",
    "CCCC": "2023-08-31 23:59:59"
  },
  "after": {
    "AAAA": "1-1112",
    "BBBB": "2022-08-31 10:10:34"
  }
}
```

i want to do this how can i do?

```json
{ 
  "AAAA": "1-1112",
  "BBBB": "2022-08-31 10:10:34",
  "CCCC": "2023-08-31 23:59:59" 
  "changed_columns": "AAAA, BBBB"
}
```

AAAA: "If you have after.AAAA, take AAAA else before.AAAA", BBBB: "If you have after.BBBB, take BBBB else before.BBBB.

AND I want to add changed_columns field like this :

```json
,"changed_columns": "AAAA, BBBB"
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: What should we do if there exist attribute `CCCC` within both of the objects ?

Comment: if both objects have CCCC then CCCC of after.CCCC should be taken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shift` operation and getting `after` values for the first. and then you can using `before` values. So if keys match with together you have an array with two element.

Now You can get first element to getting `after` values with `modify-overwrite-beta` operations and `=firstElement` function.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "after": {
        "*": {
          "$": "changed_columns[]",
          "@(1,&)": "&1"
        }
      },
      "before": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))",
      "changed_columns": "=join(', ',@(1,changed_columns))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: in this structure, How can I compare custom fields and not all fields? ex: Including AAAA and BBBB, Not including CCCC. There may be columns that I do not want in the changed_columns field.

Comment: @veganzombie You can remove it before shift with this spec: `{ "operation": "remove", "spec": { "before": { "CCCC": "" } } }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- **cardinality** spec lately after using `"after|before"` as the key in this order to determine the precedence
- exchange key-value pairs consecutively twice to determine whether
  really changed the components in order to form `"changed_columns"`

such as

```json
[
  {
    // multiplex the attributes in order to generate three independent groups
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "after|before": { // this order is important to determine the precedence in the upcoming cardinality spec
        "*": { 
          "@": "&",
          "@(0)": "l.&",
          "*": {
            "@1": "f.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // determine whether before vs. after values equal through this and next two specs
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "l": {
        "*": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
      },
      "f": {
        "*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "l|f": {
        "*": {
          "$": "lf.@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "lf": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // construct an array from those newly formed keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "lf": {
        "*": {
          "$": "changed_columns"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "changed_columns": "=join(', ',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank You so much, Barbaros Abi :)

Comment: You're welcome @veganzombie . There are some good links about Jolt such as [1](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt), [3](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview), [4](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350), [5](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html) . Have a nice study.